# Multiple devices to single power source

Tags: arduino, power

I have a power distribution board for my Quadcopter. It is powered by a 3s Lipo and the following are connected:

1. 12 Volt outlet for ESCs: 4 ESCs 12 Amp
2. 5V Outlet: Connected my 5V Gyroscope and Arduino Nano
3. 12 V outlet: Connected a receiver using 3.3 V regulator.

I don't have any additional outlets.

Question is, how do I add more devices by pulling voltage from existing outlets by connecting in parallel, as the Volts will be the same. I understand Amps will get divided.

1. Is it ok, to add more devices in parallel to let us say my 12V outlet, where I connect couple of more 3.3 V regulators to run 3.3 V devices and couple of 5V regulators to run 5V devices.

Based on the specification of LIPO and power dist module below, is there a way I can determine the max devices I can connect to both 5V and 12V outlets on my power distribution module?

here is the spec of my power distribution module:
General:

- Input voltage range (3S-4S LiPo operation): 9 - 18V DC
- Regulated 5V and 12V outputs
- 6 ESC outputs & 1 pair VCC/GND pads

ESC outputs:

- Continuous current: 25A*4 or 15A*6
- Peak current (10 seconds/minute): 30A*4 or 20A*6

BEC 5V output:

- Designed for RC Receivers, Flight controllers, OSD, and Servos.
- DC/DC synchronous buck regulator.
- Voltage: 5.0 +/- 0.1VDC
- Continuous current: 2 Amps (Max.2.5A 10s/minute)
- Output Ripple: 40mV (VIn=16V, VOut=5V@2A load)
- Short-circuit tolerant (5 seconds/minute)

BEC 12V output:

- Designed for Video TX or FPV camera with linear regulator.
- The battery should be 4S LiPo (13~18V DC)
- Voltage: 12.0 +/- 0.3VDC
- Continuous current: 500mA (Max.0.8A 5s/minute)
- Short-circuit tolerant (2 seconds/minute)

BEC 12V @ 3S LiPo

- Output voltage= 3S LiPo voltage -1V

Answer (score 1):

I posted the question in another forum and got a reply. I can power many devices from the power distribution module.As long as I do not exceed the current.